# Power BI Visuals with Measures only without summing up

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-custom-visuals

Situation:
My Report calculates the ranking developments of an accounts in one measure:

```
Class_Evolution = [Class_Minus_0] & " <-- " & [Class_Minus_1]
```

Combined with data from the source table the measures show good results per datarow.
The results look like:
[image] ...

`[Class_Minus_0]` and `[Class_Minus_1]` are measures with X-functions themself that result in a ranking (A,B,C,D) **depending on slicer selection**.
I also have a measure that counts the rows:

```
Count Values = COUNTROWS(ExhibitorClass)
```

This works so far.

Problem:
Now I need to crate visuals with the measures I created. But when I put my measures on a visual they just get summed up:
[image]

Need:

I need to built the visuals as in the example below but by using my measured instead of columns.

I have build the report without a slicer on fixed data columns with fixed ranking cutoffs and got a nice result:

[image]

However I need to be able to calculate the ranking development with the slicer so I need to build everything with measures.

How should I build my measures to get the visuals I need? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andrew, I was able to implement the following solution.
I needed a new Table matching the possible results of the measure:
[image]

Then with a VAR variable in a DAX measure the matching values could be counted:

```
Visual Count Class Evolution = 
    VAR _rank_evolution = SELECTEDVALUE('Class_Evolution'[Class_Evolution]) 
    return sumx('ExhibitorClass_Details', if([Class_Evolution] = _rank_evolution, 1,0))
```

The variable was populated form my [Class_Evolution] table and if the measure used on my [ExhibitorClass_Details] details table matched the Class_Evolution it was summed up.